# What would be the climatic and solar conditions of a canyon 1 kilometer below sea level in the West Siberian Plain?

Tags: climate, geography, sunlight, altitude

Imagine a 3km wide, 99km long canyon which is 1km below sea level, just next to the city of Surgut but not passing through. This canyon has been dug as part of some superproject which seeks to create farmlands within Siberia, and I expect this canyon to get to higher temperatures as it gets closer to the earth's core and I also expect lower radiation levels in order to create light-skinned people (thinking radiation wouldn't be low enough to prevent forest and agriculture). There is an artificial river (canal) passing through.
Other than that, no other geographic changes occurred except for the same project repeated in other places.

So, what would be the most fitting Köppen climate and Direct Normal Radiation (kWh/m²) for that canyon of this altitude, geography and latitude?

Comment: Don't forget that warm air rises...

Comment: What is its orientation?  The shade from the walls of the canyon will vary wildly, depending on that.   And, with "no other geographic changes", what would prevent this massive hole from being flooded from the local precipitation and water table?

Comment: Too narrow to work. Give it 10km width and north-south, then central areas might get extra protection from cold winds, as well as a tad better heating from tectonic effects. Yet, it's already about 2k cubic kilometers of ground to be moved... they had to be dropped somewhere. And yes, flooding will be an issue.

Comment: @Vesper maybe create an even deeper trench to store all the water?

Comment: You can't store what's not being taken away but arrives in an storage. Your bottom is already below sea level, so you need to pump excess water UP so it'll enter the world ocean, or else your canyon would be filled up with rainwater. There isn't enough power to vaporize that water, and plants don't consume all of it, so anyway you'll have excess water. It doesn't "just disappear", it flows away by rivers and into the ocean, but here you are unable to use either as free dump. And finally, dig just a tad deeper and hello supervolcano :)

Answer (score 5):

This feature would very rapidly fill with water and become a lake. Assuming that this was prevented by some means the location would not be good for agriculture. Being 1km deep and only 3km wide would present a vast amount of shadow in an already cold continental climate. This would depend to some extent on its orientation but would not be good either way. If it ran East - west the southern rim would cast a very long shadow into the canyon. If it ran north - south the eastern rim would cast a long shadow in the morning and the western rim would cast a long shadow in the afternoon.

I suspect the climate would be subarctic with boreal forest and no agriculture. There might even be some heavily shaded areas where nothing could grow due to a lack of sunlight.